# How to add additional capture group to lookahead, lookbehind regex

Tags: php, regex

I am using this regex: `(?<=\[).+?(?=\])` to match data in my test string below.

This regex matches everything between my brackets. I need to also include the '1234567890ABC...' portion of my string as well. How would I do that?

This is my test string:

```
[one] [two] [three] 1234567890ABC...
```

Comment: Split with `/[\]\[\s]+/`

Comment: Wiktor, I'm not following you. How would I do that?

Comment: Like this? `(?<=\[)[^][]*(?=\])|(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/YWACpW/1

Comment: What is the programming language / regex flavor? See https://regex101.com/r/YWACpW/2

Comment: Wictor, it's PCRE

Comment: Where are you using it?

Comment: This is confusing to me. If just that sampel data you can match all with `\w+`, but I suspect you have other characters, possible whitespaces, within those brackets? Do you have a better example? Either way, if there can be anything in between brackets than maybe [`[^[]+(?=\])|\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/13geMD/1)

Comment: Match with `[^][\s]+`, https://regex101.com/r/YWACpW/3

Comment: So, it is PHP: `preg_split('~[][\s]+~', $txt, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor and match any char except the square brackets, or match `\w+` to match only word characters.

```
(?:\[|\G(?!^)]\h\[?)\K[^][\s]+
```

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[` Match `[`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the previous match
  - `]\h\[?` Match `]`, horizontal whitespace char and optional `[`
- `)\K` Close group and reset the match buffer
- `[^][\s]+` Match 1+ times any char except square brackets or whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kudX2W/1)

Comment: I thought this was working, but it's not... I'm still trying to figure out why this is only matching partially between brackets

Comment: @NaN For which data is it not working? Try it like this `(?:\[|\G(?!^)]\h\[?)\K[^][\r\n]+` only excluding newlines instead of also whitespace chars. https://regex101.com/r/yB3wHb/1

Comment: What it looks like to me is that I want to capture whatever is between the brackets and using your regex I get no matches returned. I plugged your regex into a tester and as long as I use alphanumeric characters, it returns a match. I think you need to allow everything to be captured between the brackets

Comment: @NaN If you want to allow all between the brackets `(?:\[|\G(?!^)]\h\[?)\K[^][]+` https://regex101.com/r/f9fxZ3/1

Comment: This matches great, thanks! I am not getting a match through PHP but I can troubleshoot it from here. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Bird, can you recommend a good resource for improving my regex skills?

Comment: @NaN This is a php demo to get the matches https://3v4l.org/YZsFg You can checkout https://www.regular-expressions.info/ or https://www.rexegg.com/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I need to have 4 capture groups, not one

Comment: @NaN preg_match_all accepts a few flags, for example https://3v4l.org/BIiPe

Comment: Bird, The data being returned isn't right. I think I need to rethink my logic.

Comment: If those strings are on the same line, you can first explode on a newline and loop the separate lines https://3v4l.org/o7eqv

Comment: @NaN You could also match the format with 2 capturing groups and split the first group https://3v4l.org/piXnU

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern it's the same as the pattern you are using but it includes as well words and numbers after the brackets

```
(?<=\[).+?(?=\])\d+|\w+
```

Comment: This is working but the issue I see (my fault, sorry I wasn't clear). You're checking for digits but I want to capture everything.